# Laravel ToDo List App from Codecourse

Tags: javascript, laravel

`Onclick` event for `alert()` works but the `onClick="this.form.submit()"` doesn't cause the debug console to throw an error (as in the [video at 1:09](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtnGE7HW0io&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGH8AngyP6cp525_R_NExcR&index=6)). It just refreshes my page.

I'm following along Codecourse's Todo app tutorial. He changed `name="item"`  to `name="id"`

I'm using Laravel 4.2.17 together with wampserver 2.5

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
<h1>Your Items</h1>
<ul>
@foreach($items as $item)
   <li>
    {{ Form::open() }}
        <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="id"
        onClick="this.form.submit()"
        value="{{ $item->id }}"
        {{ $item->done ? 'checked' : '' }}
        />
        {{ $item->name }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
   </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

`{{ Form::open() }}` Simply write a `<form action="" method="post">`.

You have to set the action parameter, if you don't want to post to base.

`{{ Form::open(['url' => 'form-action-url-came-here']) }}`

And when you set up your **routes**, you have to create routes for **get**, and for **post** methods, so, your routes will be:

```
Route::get('/', ...);
Route::post('/', ...);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer...but i copied the code 1 to 1 and it should work.. I would like to use blade syntax and stick to his coding. if possible no workarounds. is there something i am missing maybe some adjustments in the config or wampserver?

Comment: I'm not meant write `<form action...`. Just tell that `{{ Form::open() }}` wont  fill the aciton attribute, if you not set it. Sorry, but I haven't seen the whole video...